# Excel Sequence Filtered Tables with Vstack

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-365

I am attempting to display a bunch of filtered tables using sequence and vstack but I'm struggling to figure out how I might be able to do this, here is the formula I'm using and I'll provide a sample of my table beneath that:

```
=VSTACK(FILTER(Table1[[Component]:[Source]],Table1[Assembly]="B"&SEQUENCE(COUNTA(B:B)),""))
```

| Assembly | Component | Quantity | Source |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10073716 | 1130FTB26WM-MS-GRPH | 1 | PHANTOM |
| 10073716 | 1530FCY27WM-MS-GRPH | 2 | PHANTOM |
| 10073716 | 1B45-GRPH | 2 | PHANTOM |
| 10073716 | GLD01-BK | 6 | STOCK |
| 10073716 | OFS-IDCT-II | 1 | STOCK |
| 10073716 | R0428 | 3 | STOCK |
| 10073716 | R0549 | 2 | STOCK |
| 10073716 | R0703 | 1 | STOCK |
| 10073716 | R0906 | 1 | STOCK |
| 10073716 | R0921 | 2 | STOCK |
| 10073716 | R0922 | 1 | STOCK |
| 10073716 | R1013 | 2 | STOCK |
| 1130FTB26WM-MS-GRPH | 1130WM-1515-MS | 1 | STOCK |
| 1130FTB26WM-MS-GRPH | 1BP | 4 | STOCK |
| 1130FTB26WM-MS-GRPH | 1CR90-GRPH | 2 | STOCK |
| 1130FTB26WM-MS-GRPH | 1F12-GRPH | 2 | STOCK |
| 1130FTB26WM-MS-GRPH | R0363 | 4 | STOCK |
| 1130FTB26WM-MS-GRPH | R0364 | 4 | STOCK |
| 1130FTB26WM-MS-GRPH | R0365 | 2 | STOCK |
| 1530FCY27WM-MS-GRPH | 1530WM-1515-MS | 1 | STOCK |
| 1530FCY27WM-MS-GRPH | 1BP | 3 | STOCK |
| 1530FCY27WM-MS-GRPH | 1CR180-GRPH | 1 | STOCK |
| 1530FCY27WM-MS-GRPH | 1F18-GRPH | 2 | STOCK |
| 1530FCY27WM-MS-GRPH | R0363 | 2 | STOCK |
| 1530FCY27WM-MS-GRPH | R0364 | 2 | STOCK |
| 1530FCY27WM-MS-GRPH | R0365 | 2 | STOCK |
| 1530FCY27WM-MS-GRPH | R0366 | 1 | STOCK |
| 1530FCY27WM-MS-GRPH | R0373 | 1 | STOCK |
| 1B45-GRPH | 1B45-BBDAC | 1 | STOCK |
| 1B45-GRPH | OM-1B45-GRPH | 1 | STOCK |

The formula shown above my sample table is being put in cell D2 (below some headers).

In cell A2 I am entering an assembly item (10073716), then in Column B I'm using a filtered list to display all of the components with a source of PHANTOM based on the assembly item in A2 (so the list in column B is 1130FTB26WM-MS-GRPH, 1530FCY27WM-MS-GRPH, & 1B45-GRPH).

I'm hoping the end result will look like below and be dynamically scalable if there are more or less items listed in column B:

| Component | Quantity | Source |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1130WM-1515-MS | 1 | STOCK |
| 1BP | 4 | STOCK |
| 1CR90-GRPH | 2 | STOCK |
| 1F12-GRPH | 2 | STOCK |
| R0363 | 4 | STOCK |
| R0364 | 4 | STOCK |
| R0365 | 2 | STOCK |
| 1530WM-1515-MS | 1 | STOCK |
| 1BP | 3 | STOCK |
| 1CR180-GRPH | 1 | STOCK |
| 1F18-GRPH | 2 | STOCK |
| R0363 | 2 | STOCK |
| R0364 | 2 | STOCK |
| R0365 | 2 | STOCK |
| R0366 | 1 | STOCK |
| R0373 | 1 | STOCK |
| 1B45-BBDAC | 1 | STOCK |
| OM-1B45-GRPH | 1 | STOCK |

I'm happy to change my strategy if this isn't possible. Thanks in advance.

Comment: So what logic are you trying to implement?

Comment: I am trying to vstack a filtered table (filtered by assembly items stored vertically in column B), the reason I'm trying to utilize sequence is because my list of assemblies in column B can change (be more or less).

To sum up what this will be used for: I'm trying to explode a Bill of Material (BOM), the items stored in column B are components that have a source = "PHANTOM" on the component list for assembly item 10073716 which is being manually input in cell A2 (end-user would input the assembly item they want to see the exploded BOM for).

Comment: I may not understand it correctly, but why not use: `=FILTER(Table1[[Component]:[Source]],(Table1[Assembly]="10073716")*(Tanble1[Source]="Phantom"),"")` ? Not sure if Assembly needs quotation marks (text) or not (number).

Comment: That will display only the components of assembly 10073716 where the source is "Phantom" (which is what I'm storing and referencing in column B). I'm trying to display the components of the components. I can accomplish what I'm asking for manually, however it is hardcoded:

'=IFNA(VSTACK(FILTER(Table1[[Component]:[Source]],(Table1[Assembly]=$B$1),""),FILTER(Table1[[Component]:[Source]],(Table1[Assembly]=$B$2),""),FILTER(Table1[[Component]:[Source]],(Table1[Assembly]=$B$3),"")),"")'

Comment: So more like `=LET(p,FILTER(Table1[Component],Table1[Source]="PHANTOM"),FILTER(Table1[[Component]:[Quantity]],ISNUMBER(XMATCH(Table1[Assembly],p))))` ?

Comment: Could you walk me through what that formula does? I'm not really sure how to use that to look at the components referenced from my list in column B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=LET(p,FILTER(Table1[Component],(Table1[Assembly]="10073716")*(Table1[Source]="PHANTOM")),
FILTER(Table1[[Component]:[Quantity]],ISNUMBER(XMATCH(Table1[Assembly],p))))
```

This first declares `p`: the filtered Table1's `[Component]` where `[Source]` equals "PHANTOM".

Then this is used inside another filter:
The filter of Table1's columns `[Component]:[Quantity]` where `[Assembly]` matches any of the `p`-assemblies.

In your example you searched for `10073716` typing it in `A2`, that would make:
`=LET(p,FILTER(Table1[Component],(Table1[Assembly]=A2)*(Table1[Source]="PHANTOM")),FILTER(Table1[[Component]:[Quantity]],ISNUMBER(XMATCH(Table1[Assembly],p))))`

*Please note that I can't tell if the `[Assembly]` are all text, or number. make sure you use the same format when searching, or use: `=LET(p,FILTER(Table1[Component],(""&Table1[Assembly]=""&E1)*(Table1[Source]="PHANTOM")),FILTER(Table1[[Component]:[Quantity]],ISNUMBER(XMATCH(Table1[Assembly],p))))`*

Comment: I really appreciate the explanation!  This gets me the results I was hoping for!